# Adjust a div's height/width by dragging its left/top border without jQuery draggable?

Tags: jquery, html

I've been struggling to achieve this! We don't want an extra dependency hence not using UI draggable.
Whatever I tried is over here: http://jsfiddle.net/wSTcJ/

```
<div id="cont">
    <div id="test">

    </div>
    <div id="test2">

    </div>
    <div id="drag">

    </div>
</div>
```

And the jQuery code is in the Fiddle.

The first div is under the second. The second one's width is kept to 0, now when I drag the drag bar, I want to adjust the width of this div, revealing its content and thus overlapping the first one's content. My code allows me to drag, but stops after some time and doesn't drag from the right to left!

Any ideas to make it working?

Comment: Please incorporate the relevant code (JavaScript/jQuery) in your question: Stack Overflow should be self contained, and without the code this question becomes nonsensical when JS Fiddle next falls over.

Comment: Thanks! I have added some of my html here and put the js in a fiddle since people could try it out there. I'll be sure to add my js next time onwards.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/wSTcJ/2/

I'm assuming you want a different bar for the vertical resizing.

Some notes of the changes I made:

- `mousemove` and `mouseup` should be bound to a parent element, usually `document`. JavaScript does not have any sort of capture mouse (like CaptureMouse() in WPF) meaning if the user moves the mouse too quickly and leaves your element then your mouse events will stop being captured by your event handlers. By binding the `document` you ensure the mouse events within your page will always be captured.
- Making a reference to your dragable object in the `mousedown` helps keep you sane.
- If you want to resize the element you'll also have to change the elements `width`.
- If you don't unbind the added `mouseup` and `mousemove` bindings they may be added multiple times, later firing as many times.
- Don't really need `drag = true` because the `mousemove` event shouldn't exist at all when the user isn't dragging.
- In order for the background to continue filling your element after it was resized I changed it's `width` and `height` to 100% in the CSS.

Most dragable divs are given an absolute positioning rather then relative. Changing this will also require some changes in the code.

Comment: Thanks man. Easy to understand code. There will be a vertical bar optionally. I mean I'll be toggling that depending on how I'll be instructed!

Comment: I added the `drag=true` cuz I was experiencing weird behavior in FF!

Comment: I tried this, the code is changing the parent containers width, not the test 2 div, whose width I want to increase!

Comment: Based on your explanation and code, I coded what I wanted! Please check it and let me know if this will work. Your expert additions welcome! http://jsfiddle.net/rutwick/UVw3F/

Comment: Also, one little problem, when I click the drag bar, its positioned to the right of the cursor. This causes mouseup to fail when I drag the div back to its original position, that is the extreme left!

Comment: So what you want is for #cont to be of a static size while it's inner div (#test2) can be resized (like a window opening and closing). See this http://jsfiddle.net/UVw3F/2/ for what I think is the intended behavior you seek. Again I advice you to place `mousemove` and `mouseup` event handlers on `$(document)` as otherwise quick mouse movement might otherwise stop firing the events you need.

Answer (score 0):

I adopted your code an solved it this way: http://jsfiddle.net/bukart/wSTcJ/1/

You had some issues in logic and usage of the methods.

```
$( function() {

    $( '#drag' ).each( function() {

        var $drag = $( this );


        $drag.parent().css( {
            'margin-left'      : $drag.parent().offset().left + 'px'
        } );

        $drag.on( 'mousedown', function( ev ) {
            var $this = $( this );
            var $parent = $this.parent();
            var poffs = $parent.position();
            var pwidth = $parent.width();

            var x = ev.pageX;
            var y = ev.pageY;

            $this.parent();

            $( document ).on( 'mousemove.dragging', function( ev ) {
                var mx = ev.pageX;
                var my = ev.pageY;

                var rx = mx - x;
                var ry = my - y;

                $parent.css( {
                    'left'       : (poffs.left + rx) + 'px',
                    'width'      : (pwidth - rx) + 'px'
                } );


            } ).on( 'mouseup.dragging mouseleave.draggign', function( ev) {
                $( document ).off( '.dragging' );
            } );


        } );

    } );

} );

​
```