# Dynamic HTML <select> height

Tags: html

Is it possible to make `<select>`'s height adjustable by the user? Simply by dragging the bottom of the expanded list.

Comment: You want to resize a select by dragging its list or you want to resize a select?

Comment: @LGSon I want to resize the <select>'s dropdown list

Answer (score 1):

Cross browser, you can't drag native drop-down boxes, but here is one suggestion how one can do.

**Edit:** But when the size property is set (`size="2"`) you can, kind of. By elaborating with the option height and the amount of item, you might achieve something useful.

The `select` has a *invisible* area outside its bottom which make it resizeable. You can also click inside the `select` and resize, though the list drops down every second time.

Resources:

- [Adjust a div's height/width by dragging its left/top border without jQuery draggable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14002556/adjust-a-divs-height-width-by-dragging-its-left-top-border-without-jquery-dragg)
- [jQuery draggable option elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086111/jquery-draggable-option-elements)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#drag').on('mousedown', function(e){
        var $dragable = $(this),
            start = $dragable.height(),
            pY = e.pageY;        
        $(document).on('mouseup', function(e){
            $(document).off('mouseup').off('mousemove');
        });
        $(document).on('mousemove', function(me){
            var my = (me.pageY - pY);            
            $dragable.css({
                height: start + my,
            });
        });                
    });
    $('#drag2').on('mousedown', function(e){
        var $dragable = $(this),
            start = $dragable.height(),
            pY = e.pageY;        
        $(document).on('mouseup', function(e){
            $(document).off('mouseup').off('mousemove');
        });
        $(document).on('mousemove', function(me){
            var my = (me.pageY - pY);            
            $dragable.css({
                height: start + my,
            });
        });                
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 30px;
}
div{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: row-resize;
  height: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
select{
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
option {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  height: 25%;          /* sizable when size property is set to more than 1 */
}
#drag2 {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div id="drag">
    <select>
      <option>nr1</option>
      <option>nr2</option>
      <option>nr3</option>
      <option>nr4</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div id="drag2">
    <select size="2">
      <option>nr1</option>
      <option>nr2</option>
      <option>nr3</option>
      <option>nr4</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Currently I'm working on the solution basing on
"Adjust a div's height/width by dragging its left/top border without jQuery draggable?" - thank you for that suggestion. I'll post once I figure it out.

In your snippet the selected value box is resizable - not the dropdown. That's what I'm looking for.

Comment: @PramusPL Option element doesn't have many styleable properties, and height is not one of them. If you need a styleable select you need to a´make one from ul/li or div/span or something.

Comment: Again, not closed <select> (like in your snippet) and not each option - I would like to adjust the height of the expanded select so the whole list of options :)

Comment: @PramusPL You want to change a select's size property, which defines how many visible option elements it should have?

Comment: No, the height change has to be smooth, not related to number of visible elements.

Comment: @PramusPL You can't resize the height of the drop-down-list on a native drop-down, you need to make your own, and I believe a `ul/li` would probably be the best.

Comment: @PramusPL Made an update of my answer that might help.

Comment: Unfortunately it excludes the usage of a drop-down. I'll try with a list instead as you suggested.

Comment: Okay, I figured it out by using 'chosen', playing a bit with it and adding a div mentioned in the related answer. Unfortunately I cannot post it since the question has been marked as duplicate (what IMHO is not 100% true)

Comment: @PramusPL My answer is a community wiki where I gain no reps. or credits, so feel free to update it with your solution and add your name to it. This way future readers get access to your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Many textarea resizer js pluggins should work with select too...