# Make Bootstrap 4 dropdown have dynamic height

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make Bootstrap 4 dropdown have this style: [slinky.js.org](https://slinky.js.org/)

This is what I have by now: https://codepen.io/nht910/pen/yLexeEM

Main code:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">

    <div class="main-container">
        <div class="menu-container">
            <div class="menu-1">
                <span>Link-1</span>
                <button class="button-1">arrow-1</button>
            </div>
            <div class="menu-2">
                <span>Link-2</span>
                <button class="button-2">arrow-2</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="submenu-container">
            <div class="submenu-1">  <!-- submenu of .menu-1 -->
                <div class="arrow-back">
                    <button class="button-back-1">Arrow back 1</button>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span>Child 1</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="submenu-2">  <!-- submenu of .menu-2 -->
                <div class="arrow-back">
                    <button class="button-back-2">Arrow back 2</button>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span>Child 2</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

To make dropdown has slide effect:

- I set two classes `.submenu-1` and `.submenu-2` to `display: none`, and when user click on arrow button, corresponding submenu will be shown and slide to it.
- when user click on arrow back, it will slide back to main menu, and after finish sliding effect, it will hide submenu.

That is what I have for now. But I don't know how to resize dropdown's height to fit content inside it (dynamic height) like [slinky.js.org](https://slinky.js.org/).

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: https://codepen.io/nht910/pen/OJMobEm

I change height of dropdown using JS with `.submenu-1` is the content I want dropdown to fit:

```
$('.dropdown-menu').height($('.submenu-1').outerHeight());
```

But it got one problem. At the first time I click on `arrow button` (it is the first time height of dropdown changed), the transition animation doesn't work. But after that, it work perfectly. So I add another line at global to make the first time that height is changed happen on page load. And now it work perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try using hide & code when you click.

you can simply do it by using jQuery

$("selector").hide() & $("selector").show()

when user clicks your custom buttons

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how to make dropdown has dynamic height that fit with its content?

Comment: Try creating custom css, if you can, give the dynamic content padding or something like that based on the content. Same you can do using JQuery for giving dynamic css, quite old method now. You can find multiple solutions on StackOverflow

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34332614/dynamic-html-select-height

Comment: I got a solution here: [https://codepen.io/nht910/pen/OJMobEm](https://codepen.io/nht910/pen/OJMobEm). It works quiet good but at the first time click on `Arrow button`, height resize doesn't have transition effect. But after first time, it work perfectly. Can you please help me to debug it?

Comment: Thank you. I know how to fix it.

Comment: Okay great, actually I was afk from the platform, was sleeping